# updating with modified date, not todays date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-365

Im a total novice at VBA code, but from my googling it looks as if I’ll need VBA for what I’m looking for. I have a sheet where there is a “notes” cell, and a separate cell which contains the date of when this notes cell was last updated. I am needing the "date of update" cell (which is in column D) to be automatically updated with the date when the notes cell (column H) is updated. My google-jitsu is only finding me the today function, which isn’t working because Client X may have an update date of today, but Client Y may have been last week.

I.e., to have D2 update whenever H2 updates, d3 whenever h3 updates, etc)

Thank y’all so much in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a formula in a cell? (See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/Formulas-and-functions-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9#ID0EAABAAA=Formulas ) From your description, a simple formula of `=H2` in cell `D2` will do what you want. Copy the formula in cell `D2` to `D3`, `D4`, etc and Excel will take care of the rest.

Comment: Will this allow D2 to update to the date H2 was modified?  AFAIK, it just copies the cell contents.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel does not provide a direct means through any of its worksheet functions (such as `CELL()`) for determining when the value of a cell was last updated. One possibility, therefore, is to consider use of VBA.

VBA does provide a mechanism for dealing with the problem of automatically capturing the date of modification of one cell, but this involves the use of "events".

Specifically, the `Worksheet_Change` event is triggered whenever a change is made to a worksheet. User written code can be made to run whenever such an event is triggered and this code can be designed to (1) identify if any of the "notes" cells in column H have changed and (2) to insert the date in the corresponding "date of update" cells in column D.

I don't propose writing that code for you as SuperUser is not a free code writing service but will instead point you at the following links:

1. Microsoft's own "documentation" about [worksheet events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events) and, in particular, the [Worksheet_Change](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event. This documentation is quite terse and compact.
2. This lengthy article from [TrumpExcel](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/) is a good starting point for learning about events generally in Excel and covers worksheet events as well as other types of events. Covering the same ground but in a slightly different way is this article from [AutomateExcel](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/events/) - take particular note of its warning about the [Dangers of using code in events](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/events/#Dangers_of_Using_Code_in_Events) and how to avoid these by using code to temporarily disable further events from triggering and then, once your own event code has done its job, re-enabling events.

Once you have mastered event programming (and as a self-confessed VBA novice it will take some investment of time and learning), you will be in a position where you can write event code that will automate the task specified in your question.

Once you get to this point, and assuming that you are using Excel and VBA, you will be able to use VBA's `Date` function in your code to capture the current system date and when you detect that a cell in column `H` has been changed write this date into the corresponding cell in column `D`. Note that this is different from using worksheet functions such as  `TODAY()` or `NOW()` in a formula for such a cell. Running code to update a cell's value is similar, in effect, to typing the value into the cell - the value stays unchanged until either new code affecting the cell is executed or the user takes some type of action to change the cell's value. In contrast, applying a formula to a cell can potentially change the value of that cell every time the worksheet is recalculated.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I’m so glad for the resources, I’d love to learn how to write macros!

Comment: If this is a good answer for you, please consider accepting it.  To write macros in Excel you need to learn about Excel's object model and how to write VBA code. This article from Microsoft is worth a read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office